# At what point does one decide a font is in the public domain?

Tags: fonts, copyright

I've tried to find who created the font Orion Esperanto Normala (which is quite similar to Arial), but none of the distributions I've found have either stated the author's name or included any kind of licence. So it sounds as though it's in the public domain and can therefore be used and modified at will by anybody for either private or commercial purposes. But is that accurate?

Comment: I don't think there is a point where anyone can simply decide something, anything, is public domain merely because the author can't be discovered. But.. there may be a point where usage moves forward with the understanding the author may present themselves at some later date and will need to be dealt with at that time. (I'm not a lawyer.. which is really who you should be asking.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a ТrueТype font, then you may assume that it is public-domain only some time after the year 2061; if its OpenType, you may do that assumption after 2070.

The thing is, copyright makes it so that *nothing* is to be ever assumed to be in public domain. Everything is copyrighted, unless explicitly containing a disclaimer that it is in public domain.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's a Truetype font. What rule are you applying to get the date 2061? The metadata on its .ttf file say it was last modified in December 1993.

Comment: @ruffle thats 70 years since truetypes started to be used. So no truetype ever used will be public domain unless released. Not all places allow public domain release. Hence creative commons.

Comment: Patience is a virtue ...